# Need to make WinDLX work on Windows

Tags: windows, compatibility

For an architecture course, we have been told to install this software called [WinDLX](http://electro.fisica.unlp.edu.ar/arq/downloads/Software/WinDLX/windlx.html). I downloaded the zip file and when I run it, I get an error saying **This app can't run on your PC**.

[image: This app can't run on your PC]

I tried Compatibility Mode with Windows 7 and Windows XP SP3 but none of them work. I read the [manual](http://cs.uns.edu.ar/~jechaiz/arquitectura/windlx/wdlxtut.pdf) and it said ***You will need Windows 3.0 or higher for this simulation***. Does this mean that this is a 16-bit program and hence won't run on my 64-bit Windows 8 Pro box?

So, I want to know if there is a way to make this run on my machine or is there a newer, alternative software which does the same job as WinDLX?

**UPDATE:** Taking [magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981)'s suggestion, I installed [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) and then I ran the following commands. Ultimately, I get the error saying, **This program must be run under Microsoft Windows**. Any ideas?

[image: This program must be run under Microsoft Windows]

Comment: read my additional information. If this is a 16Bit Windows tool, setup a VM with a 32Bit Windows which can run 16Bit tools.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Btw, do you know of any alternative software which does the same thing as this?

Comment: I have no idea what this tool is doing, so I can't tell you alternatives.

Comment: some possible alternatives at the bottom of the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLX), namely: [dlxSimulator](http://www.davidviner.com/dlx.php) - you may have to compile source to make it work in windows. [openDLX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opendlx/) - looks to be written in java. There's also an '[Escape DLX simulator](http://trappist.elis.ugent.be/escape/)' but I got 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that this is a 16-bit program and hence won't run on my
>   64-bit Windows 8 Pro box?

this is correct. 64Bit Windows can't run 16 Bit programs. you must use the 3rd party tool [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). This is because of a [limitation with 64Bit CPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes). Here is a guide how to use Turbo C++ under [DOSBox](http://blog.bestsoftware4download.com/2010/02/how-to-install-turbo-c-on-windows-7-64bit/). This should help you to get your tool running.

I can also be a 16Bit Win3.x software. In this case you need a 32Bit Windows (Windows 95) in Virtual Machine. You can use Hyper-V which is included in Windows 8 Pro to create a virtual Machine.

André

Comment: This is indeed a 16-bit software eh?

Comment: yes, this is a 16Bit Application from 1992.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Installed DOSBox. Followed the instructions on that site. When I run WinDLX, it says **This program must be run under Microsoft Windows**. I will update my question with screenshots.

Comment: I've added new information. It can also be a 16Bit Windows application. You need a 32Bit VM to run it.

Comment: Will it run in Windows 7 32 bit? From where do I get Windows 95 now lol? And yeah, I edited the question.

Comment: the older the Windows version is, the better are the chances to run old 16Bit tools.

Comment: Do you know from where to get a Windows 95 ISO?

Comment: somewhere in the Internet you should find one. I can't give you links.